# Average two rows if both conditions are met

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe named `df` which looks like this;

```
id face value
1   r   15
1   r   11
1   t   16
1   t   17
2   r   13
2   r   25
2   t   12
2   t   18
3   r   30
3   r   20
3   t   19
3   t   10
```

So I need to average each row, if both conditions are met. The conditions are; if `id` and `face` are the same, then average `value`.

For example, if `id=1` and `face=r` then average values `15+11`and put the calculated value `13` in a new column. I have to do this for entire dataframe (2000 rows with 500 different `id`).

**PS;** For each `face` I have to have different columns. I mean for example, if `id=1` and `face=r` put average `value` in a new column called `newr`, if `id=2` and `face=r` put average `value` in a new column called `newr` as well. Then if `id=1` and `face=t` put average `value` in a new column called `newt`. And the output will be like this;

```
id face newr newt
1   r    13
1   t        16.5
2   r   19
2   t        15
```

Here's my `str(df1)`

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  340 obs. of  26 variables:
 $ id         : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 7 7 ...
 $ nirid      : chr  "bx5xtx1" "ax5xrx2" "bx5xrx2" "bx5xtx2" ...
 $ group      : Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","r": 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ section    : Factor w/ 3 levels "","r","t": 3 2 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 ...
 $ face       : Factor w/ 3 levels "","1","2": 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 ...
 $ sample     : chr  "B3C-3D" "B3C-3D" "B3C-3D" "B3C-3D" ...
 $ treatment  : chr  "control" "control" "control" "control" ...
 $ width      : num  1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ thick      : num  1.02 1.02 1.02 1.02 1.02 ...
 $ length     : num  16 16 16 16 16 ...
 $ testweight : num  126 126 126 126 126 ...
 $ maxload    : num  418 418 418 418 418 418 418 418 436 436 ...
 $ loadppl    : num  251 251 251 251 251 251 251 251 258 258 ...
 $ ppldistance: num  0.139 0.139 0.139 0.139 0.139 ...
 $ scmor      : num  0.399 0.399 0.399 0.399 0.399 ...
 $ scmoe      : num  5.53e-05 5.53e-05 5.53e-05 5.53e-05 5.53e-05 ...
 $ failure    : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ mcweight   : num  107 107 107 107 107 ...
 $ odweight   : num  94.1 94.1 94.1 94.1 94.1 94.1 94.1 94.1 90.3 90.3 ...
 $ mc         : num  13.3 13.3 13.3 13.3 13.3 ...
 $ sgsc       : num  0.415 0.415 0.415 0.415 0.415 ...
 $ scmorpsi   : num  58 58 58 58 58 ...
 $ scmoepsi   : num  8.03 8.03 8.03 8.03 8.03 ...
 $ rows       : chr  "9" "10" "11" "12" ...
 $ value        :Class 'AsIs'  num [1:238000] 0.0147 -0.0169 -0.0152 0.0135 -0.0107 ...
 $ sg42       :Class 'AsIs'  num [1:235280] 1.86e-04 9.39e-05 8.94e-05 1.83e-04 8.86e-05 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

**Updated**

Here's small part of actual dataset using `dput(droplevels(head(data, 20)))`

```
structure(list(id = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), nirid = c("bx5xtx1", 
"ax5xrx2", "bx5xrx2", "bx5xtx2", "bx5xrx1", "ax5xtx1", "ax5xrx1", 
"ax5xtx2", "ax7xrx1", "ax7xtx2", "ax7xrx2", "ax7xtx1", "ax8xrx2", 
"ax8xtx1", "ax8xrx1", "ax8xtx2", "ax9xtx2", "bx9xtx2", "ax9xrx2", 
"ax9xtx1"), group = c("b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "a"), 
    section = c("t", "r", "r", "t", "r", "t", "r", "t", "r", 
    "t", "r", "t", "r", "t", "r", "t", "t", "t", "r", "t"), face = c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), sample = c("B3C-3D", "B3C-3D", "B3C-3D", 
    "B3C-3D", "B3C-3D", "B3C-3D", "B3C-3D", "B3C-3D", "B3C-1E", 
    "B3C-1E", "B3C-1E", "B3C-1E", "B1C-2D", "B1C-2D", "B1C-2D", 
    "B1C-2D", "A3C-2C", "A3C-2C", "A3C-2C", "A3C-2C"), treatment = c("control", 
    "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
    "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
    "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
    "control"), width = c("1.003", "1.003", "1.003", "1.003", 
    "1.003", "1.003", "1.003", "1.003", "1.021", "1.021", "1.021", 
    "1.021", "1.02", "1.02", "1.02", "1.02", "1.033", "1.033", 
    "1.033", "1.033"), thick = c("1.02", "1.02", "1.02", "1.02", 
    "1.02", "1.02", "1.02", "1.02", "1.043", "1.043", "1.043", 
    "1.043", "1.025", "1.025", "1.025", "1.025", "1.029", "1.029", 
    "1.029", "1.029"), length = c("16", "16", "16", "16", "16", 
    "16", "16", "16", "15.98", "15.98", "15.98", "15.98", "16.016", 
    "16.016", "16.016", "16.016", "16.005", "16.005", "16.005", 
    "16.005"), testweight = c("126", "126", "126", "126", "126", 
    "126", "126", "126", "121.4", "121.4", "121.4", "121.4", 
    "144.1", "144.1", "144.1", "144.1", "119.6", "119.6", "119.6", 
    "119.6"), maxload = c(418L, 418L, 418L, 418L, 418L, 418L, 
    418L, 418L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 631L, 631L, 631L, 631L, 
    486L, 486L, 486L, 486L), loadppl = c("251", "251", "251", 
    "251", "251", "251", "251", "251", "258", "258", "258", "258", 
    "296", "296", "296", "296", "255", "255", "255", "255"), 
    ppldistance = c("0.1388", "0.1388", "0.1388", "0.1388", "0.1388", 
    "0.1388", "0.1388", "0.1388", "0.155", "0.155", "0.155", 
    "0.155", "0.1412", "0.1412", "0.1412", "0.1412", "0.1488", 
    "0.1488", "0.1488", "0.1488"), scmor = c("0.399330740757585", 
    "0.399330740757585", "0.399330740757585", "0.399330740757585", 
    "0.399330740757585", "0.399330740757585", "0.399330740757585", 
    "0.399330740757585", "0.391336060622532", "0.391336060622532", 
    "0.391336060622532", "0.391336060622532", "0.587001478757759", 
    "0.587001478757759", "0.587001478757759", "0.587001478757759", 
    "0.442958394865818", "0.442958394865818", "0.442958394865818", 
    "0.442958394865818"), scmoe = c("5.5328050375923e-05", "5.5328050375923e-05", 
    "5.5328050375923e-05", "5.5328050375923e-05", "5.5328050375923e-05", 
    "5.5328050375923e-05", "5.5328050375923e-05", "5.5328050375923e-05", 
    "4.6792031310635e-05", "4.6792031310635e-05", "4.6792031310635e-05", 
    "4.6792031310635e-05", "6.2150955161815e-05", "6.2150955161815e-05", 
    "6.2150955161815e-05", "6.2150955161815e-05", "4.9585347590597e-05", 
    "4.9585347590597e-05", "4.9585347590597e-05", "4.9585347590597e-05"
    ), failure = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), mcweight = c("106.6", 
    "106.6", "106.6", "106.6", "106.6", "106.6", "106.6", "106.6", 
    "102.1", "102.1", "102.1", "102.1", "121.9", "121.9", "121.9", 
    "121.9", "100.7", "100.7", "100.7", "100.7"), odweight = c("94.1", 
    "94.1", "94.1", "94.1", "94.1", "94.1", "94.1", "94.1", "90.3", 
    "90.3", "90.3", "90.3", "107.1", "107.1", "107.1", "107.1", 
    "88.3", "88.3", "88.3", "88.3"), mc = c("13.2837407013815", 
    "13.2837407013815", "13.2837407013815", "13.2837407013815", 
    "13.2837407013815", "13.2837407013815", "13.2837407013815", 
    "13.2837407013815", "13.0675526024363", "13.0675526024363", 
    "13.0675526024363", "13.0675526024363", "13.8188608776844", 
    "13.8188608776844", "13.8188608776844", "13.8188608776844", 
    "14.0430351075878", "14.0430351075878", "14.0430351075878", 
    "14.0430351075878"), sgsc = c("0.414649099500969", "0.414649099500969", 
    "0.414649099500969", "0.414649099500969", "0.414649099500969", 
    "0.414649099500969", "0.414649099500969", "0.414649099500969", 
    "0.385028360121945", "0.385028360121945", "0.385028360121945", 
    "0.385028360121945", "0.461392466167132", "0.461392466167132", 
    "0.461392466167132", "0.461392466167132", "0.376174963976185", 
    "0.376174963976185", "0.376174963976185", "0.376174963976185"
    ), scmorpsi = c("57.9580175265", "57.9580175265", "57.9580175265", 
    "57.9580175265", "57.9580175265", "57.9580175265", "57.9580175265", 
    "57.9580175265", "56.79768659253", "56.79768659253", "56.79768659253", 
    "56.79768659253", "85.1961507631", "85.1961507631", "85.1961507631", 
    "85.1961507631", "64.2900427962", "64.2900427962", "64.2900427962", 
    "64.2900427962"), scmoepsi = c("8.0301959907", "8.0301959907", 
    "8.0301959907", "8.0301959907", "8.0301959907", "8.0301959907", 
    "8.0301959907", "8.0301959907", "6.7912962715", "6.7912962715", 
    "6.7912962715", "6.7912962715", "9.0204579335", "9.0204579335", 
    "9.0204579335", "9.0204579335", "7.1967122773", "7.1967122773", 
    "7.1967122773", "7.1967122773"), rows = 9:28, value = c("0.014680833", 
    "-0.0169", "-0.015241563", "0.013507307", "-0.010687351", 
    "0.000479", "-0.0311", "-7.18e-05", "-0.037", "-0.00349", 
    "-0.0395", "-0.000859", "-0.018", "0.000127", "-0.0234", 
    "0.00215", "-0.0165", "-0.0162", "-0.0286", "-0.0214"), sg42 = c("0.000185853584415584", 
    "9.39393939393943e-05", "8.93772943722944e-05", "0.000183087277056277", 
    "8.86156017316018e-05", "0.000180270562770563", "9.02597402597403e-05", 
    "0.0001831779004329", "8.26839826839824e-05", "0.000167605411255411", 
    "8.44155844155841e-05", "0.000175891774891775", "9.1774891774892e-05", 
    "0.000180465367965368", "9.02597402597405e-05", "0.000178874458874459", 
    "0.000160822510822511", "0.000154978354978355", "8.26839826839826e-05", 
    "0.000159090909090909")), .Names = c("id", "nirid", "group", 
"section", "face", "sample", "treatment", "width", "thick", "length", 
"testweight", "maxload", "loadppl", "ppldistance", "scmor", "scmoe", 
"failure", "mcweight", "odweight", "mc", "sgsc", "scmorpsi", 
"scmoepsi", "rows", "value", "sg42"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Expected outcome columns are `newr`,`newt`, `newrsg42`and `newtsg42`

Thank you very much :)

Comment: 2000 row dataset is not a big dataset.  Please do check the `str` and see if the value column is numeric.

Comment: @akrun When I use `str` it says;

`value        :Class 'AsIs'  num [1:238000] 0.0147 -0.0169 -0.0152 0.0135 -0.0107`

Comment: Can you update the full `str` in your post..  The 'AsIs' can occur in cases of `list`.

Comment: @akrun Since it was too long to write in comments, I edited the question and put `str(df1)` there

Comment: Try changing the `class` to numeric by `df1[, value:= as.numeric(value)]` and then do the dcast

Comment: @akrun When I used `df1[, value:= as.numeric(value)]` I got this message;
`Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(df1, , `:=`(value, as.numeric(value))) :
  Supplied 238000 items to be assigned to 340 items of column 'value' (237660 unused)`

Comment: How did you created this dataset.  As showed in the `str` you have only 340 rows and this `value` is of length `238000`.  My understanding is that it is a `list` column in the dataset.

Comment: @akrun `value` is near infrared spectroscopy data which has 700 columns, so I converted `value` into matrix, took 2nd derivated Savitzky Golay of `value` and called it `sg42`, made dataframe with the rest of the data (e.g. `width`,`length` etc) and at the end, combined datafarame and `value` matrix into one datafile - `smooth<-data.frame(data,value=I(value),sg42=I(sg42))`

Comment: the `I(value)` is the problem.  It creates `list` column in your data.frame with `AsIs` class

Comment: @akrun hmmm... so what should I do with it? change `value` class?

Comment: I am guessing, your dataset was created similar to this `data <- data.frame(id = 1:6); m1 <- matrix(1:36, 6, 6) str(data.frame(data, value =I(c(m1))))#
'data.frame':   36 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ id   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 ... $ value:Class 'AsIs'  int [1:36] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...` but still not exactly as you showed because of the lengths.

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example with expected output

Comment: @akrun I added small part of dataset to question. Thanks

Comment: Can you use `dput` to show the example.  It gives the correct structure and also please update with the expected i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(yourdata, 20)))`

Comment: For some reason, it is not showing the exact structure as you showed earlier `$ value      : chr  "0.014680833" "-0.0169" "-0.015241563" "0.013507307" ...`

Comment: @akrun I changed my data structure and I worked fine. Thank you :)

Comment: What i meant is that your 'value' column in `character` class and it is a `vector` and not a `list` (I checked the new structure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we need the output in a 'wide' format, use `dcast` from `data.table` and specify the `fun.aggregate` as `mean`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), id + face ~ paste0("new", face), value.var="value", mean)
#   id face newr newt
#1:  1    r   13  NaN
#2:  1    t  NaN 16.5
#3:  2    r   19  NaN
#4:  2    t  NaN 15.0
#5:  3    r   25  NaN
#6:  3    t  NaN 14.5
```

---

Or another option is `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(id, face) %>% 
  summarise(MeanValue = mean(value)) %>% 
  mutate(newface = paste0("new", face)) %>%
  spread(newface, MeanValue)
#    id  face  newr  newt
#  <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     r    13    NA
#2     1     t    NA  16.5
#3     2     r    19    NA
#4     2     t    NA  15.0
#5     3     r    25    NA
#6     3     t    NA  14.5
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(id = sample(1:50, 1e7, replace=TRUE), 
                face = sample(letters, 1e7, replace=TRUE),
               value = rnorm(1e7), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 <- copy(df1)

system.time({
 dcast(setDT(df1), id + face ~ paste0("new", face), value.var="value", mean)    
 })
#  user  system elapsed 
#  1.95    0.01    1.96 
system.time({
 reshape(transform(aggregate(value~face+id,df1,mean),time=face),dir='w',
                     idvar=c('id','face'));
 })
#   user  system elapsed 
#  16.36    1.00   17.38
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), face = c("r", "r", "t", "t", "r", "r", "t", "t", "r", 
"r", "t", "t"), value = c(15L, 11L, 16L, 17L, 13L, 25L, 12L, 
18L, 30L, 20L, 19L, 10L)), .Names = c("id", "face", "value"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. I missed an explanation in my question. For each each 'face' I have to have different columns. I mean for example, if `id=1` and `face=r` put average `value` in a new column called `newr`, if `id=2` and `face=r` put average `value` in a new column called `newr` as well. Then if `id=1` and `face=t` put average `value` in a new column called `newt`. I edited my question and put this explanation there too.

Comment: @MaMi Can you update your post with the expected output

Comment: Thank you, but when I run the code, I get this error;
`Error in gmean(nir) : grpn [340] != length(x) [238000] in gsum`

Comment: @MaMi I am not getting any error with the example you showed

Comment: Anyway pm is online.

Comment: @MaMi I provided two solutions.  You can check the other one.

Comment: @akrun Thanks, both of your solution work fine with `data` provided here, I think since my actual `value` column is large matrix, I got the error

Comment: @MaMi Both dplyr and data.table can handle very large datasets.  It could be that there is something in the data which creates the error.  Can you check the `str(yourdata)`

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution using `aggregate()` and `reshape()`:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1L,1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,2L,3L,3L,3L,3L),face=c('r','r','t','t','r','r','t','t','r','r','t','t'),value=c(15L,11L,16L,17L,13L,25L,12L,18L,30L,20L,19L,10L),stringsAsFactors=F);
reshape(transform(aggregate(value~face+id,df,mean),time=face),dir='w',idvar=c('id','face'));
##   face id value.r value.t
## 1    r  1      13      NA
## 2    t  1      NA    16.5
## 3    r  2      19      NA
## 4    t  2      NA    15.0
## 5    r  3      25      NA
## 6    t  3      NA    14.5
```

Comment: When I used `aggregate()` and `reshape()` on my data, I got the following error;
`Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ""function"" to a data.frame`

Comment: @MaMi It's likely you are passing `df` as the second argument to `aggregate()`, just as I do in my solution, but you haven't assigned `df` to a data.frame. If this is correct, then `df` will bind to the `df()` function in the built-in stats package. You must pass your data.frame variable as the second argument to `aggregate()` for the code to work.

Comment: Thanks the problem was with my data structure! I fixed it and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
for( i in unique(df1$id)){
  for(j in unique(df1$face=="r"[df1$id==i])){
      for(l in unique(df1$face == "t"[df1$id==i])){
       df1$newr[df1$id==i & df1$face=="r"] <- mean(df1$value[df1$id==i & df1$face=="r"])
        df1$newt[df1$id==i & df1$face=="t"] <- mean(df1$value[df1$id==i & df1$face=="t"])
     }
   }
}


df1 <- df1[!duplicated(df1[,c("id","face")]),]

> df1
   id face newr newt
1   1    r   13   NA
3   1    t   NA 16.5
5   2    r   19   NA
7   2    t   NA 15.0
9   3    r   25   NA
11  3    t   NA 14.5
```